# How to generate such sounds as in example?

Tags: audio

I found these files on Internet:

[1.wav](http://rgho.st/8gcdRqlb6)
[2.wav](http://rgho.st/68sZ4YBKC)
[3.wav](http://rgho.st/7mN2hM58P)
[4.wav](http://rgho.st/75ndN2zXf)

How to generate such sounds?

Geno Chen wrote "Acoustic Grand Piano (Instrument #0)"

What to do next?

Comment: Those wav links give error: 503 Service Unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/

There is a Center focused on Music and Acoustics at Stanford University and their website has many resources. There are several papers on computer generation of musical instrument sounds.